# How do I export hyperlinks from a list to Excel and keep the links clickable?

Tags: hyperlink, export-to-excel

I have a List and one of the fields (Data Collection) is set up as Multiple lines of text, with 8 lines allowed for editing via Enhanced Rich Text Editor. The field can hold simply notes (bulleted, numbered, paragraph) or a hyperlink to a data file. The issue is when I export this list, the records in this field that have hyperlinks are not being exported as hyperlinks, but as regular text instead. The exported data will be refreshed multiple times and can contain a couple of hundred records, but not all of the records in this field will contain hyperlinks.

If I press `F2` and hit `Enter` a link becomes clickable, but I won't always be the one using this data/report and there will be a couple hundred records. I tried a couple of different macros to mimic the F2/Enter action, but neither worked:

**macro 1:**

```
Sub ApplyF2()
    Selection.Value = Selection.FormulaR1C1
End Sub
```

**macro 2:**

```
Sub reEnter()
 For Each r In Selection
     r.Formula = r.Formula
 Next
 End Sub
```

I also tried calculations to identify which cells had hyperlinks (below), but those made every cell clickable:

```
=IFIF(LEN([@[Work Stream Lead - - Data Collection]])<2,"",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("\\",[@[Work Stream Lead - - Data Collection]])),HYPERLINK([@[Work Stream Lead - - Data Collection]]),IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("//",[@[Work Stream Lead - - Data Collection]])),HYPERLINK([@[Work Stream Lead - - Data Collection]]),[@[Work Stream Lead - - Data Collection1]])))="","",IF(LEN([@[Work Stream Lead - - Data Collection]])<2,"",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("\\",[@[Work Stream Lead - - Data Collection]])),HYPERLINK([@[Work Stream Lead - - Data Collection]]),IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("//",[@[Work Stream Lead - - Data Collection]])),HYPERLINK([@[Work Stream Lead - - Data Collection]],"")))
```

I would like my list to export the hyperlink as clickable without having to apply any formulas or macros, as I will not be the person using and maintaining this file.

Could you please advise me on the right approach?